# ID is being displayed instead of the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `items` and `builds`.
Whatever I do, I just cannot get the name of the items to be displayed for `How do I output name instead of ID?` and the rest. It just displays the ID :/.

In the code provided below, the ID of the items are being displayed instead of the name of the item with that ID. How do I display the name of the item?

```
<% current_user.builds.each do |build| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= build.hero.name%></td> 
    <td><%= build.user.email%></td> 
    <td><%= build.name %></td> 
    <td><%= build.starting_items %></td> 
    <td><%= build.early_items %></td> 
    <td><%= build.core_items %></td> 
    <td><%= build.situational_items %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/imjp/DotA-Items

Basically, what I want to do is to be able to enter the id of an item in my form that later on gets displayed as the item name.

I'm not even sure if the name starting_items is the best for this, or if i should just use `item_id`. Because I'm planning on adding a lot of different inputs where users can enter items that need to be displayed as names.
Do you think the name `starting_items` is good for one of the fields, or should I use `item_id`? 

Isn't there a way I can display the name of an item with ruby by doing something like `Item.name.find(build.starting_items)` or something? Since the `starting_items` value is an `item_id`?

Comment: Try adding: `<td><%= p build.inspect %></td>` and `<td><%= p build.hero.inspect %></td>` and show us the output for one of the build objects

Comment: Also - in your question you are saying you can't get the name for an *item*, but the code is for *builds*... have you given us the correct code?

Comment: I've added the github repo as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you call build.starting_items which I assume is a named scope or method call you are probably returning an array of the items themselves.

Following this it's likely that each of the items if being inspected or you are seeing the output of item.to_s.

In order to display the names of these items instead of the object id you probably wish to use something like:

```
<td><%= build.starting_items.map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>
```

This will call map on the array and pass out each of the names and then join them (you could also use .to_sentence in Rails).

Comment: Hey thanks for replying Steve. However, I do not have an array that is being returned or anything. I think I should have `item_id` as the column name instead of `situational_items`, `starting_items` and so forth. I'm going to post the github project so you can take a look.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the methods situational_items and starting_items actually are. The fact they were plural just made me assume they were arrays.

Comment: I'm still very new to rails: this is my first app, so some things might not have been done correctly by me. The columns `situational_items` and `starting_items` are not methods, they're just strings. I just realized I need to change those to integers to see if that will help.

Comment: I have posted another answer. I will remove this answer assuming the other one is along the right lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ok from re-reading what you've written in response to the other answer, I now *guess* that the column that you're having trouble with is:

```
<td><%= build.starting_items %></td>
```

(let me know if that guess is wrong and tell me the right one).

Rails doesn't automatically know that you want to see the *names* of these items. It will give you exactly what you've asked for - and here you have asked for the set of actual items... not the *names* of the set of items.  To turn these item-objects into a list of the names of the items, you must call the "name" method on each item. you can do that using the code the other answer gave:

```
<td><%= build.starting_items.map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>
```

**UPDATE**

ok, reading through your codebase.
The problem is that you aren't actually saving the starting_items as actual items. In the form where you create a "build", you have the starting_items field as a select-box... the select box stores a set of *ids*. and id is just an integer value.
nowhere in your code do you turn that set of integer id values into *actual Item objects*.

So... when you go to look at that list once more... it's still just a set of integers.

To see the names of the Items that have those ids, you will need to actually instantiate those Item objects... and *then* call the 'name' method on them eg:

```
<td><%= Item.find(build.starting_items).map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>
```

Note: you'll also need to add basic checks eg that build.starting_items is not empty, and that the ids are in fact valid ids...

Comment: Thanks for answering Taryn. I tried placing the code you've provided but I get a `nomethoderror: undefined method `map' for #<Item:0x8126430>`

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is to be able to enter the id of an item in my form that later on gets displayed as the item name.


I'm not even sure if the name starting_items is the best for this, or if i should just use `item_id`. Because I'm planning on adding a lot of different inputs where users can enter items that need to be displayed as names.
Do you think the name `starting_items` is good for one of the fields, or should I use `item_id`? 



Isn't there a way I can display the name of an item with ruby by doing something like `Item.name.find(build.starting_items)` or something?

Comment: As i said - you'll need to add basic checks. In this case, you're getting the "undefined method" error because you only passed a single id, and thus it wasn't returned as an array. You should probably add a check for : "if build.starting_items.length < 1" or just force it to be an array eg "Item.find([build.starting_items].compact)" ...

Comment: As to whether it's a good idea... that's another question entirely. It seems to work - you just have to actually turn them into real Items before trying to call methods on them ;)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Unfortunately, I don't know how to add basic checks. Seems like Chinese to me. I'm going to dig into some Rails books.

Comment: By "basic checks" I mean basic error and edge-case detection eg "if starting_items.present?" and "if (item = Item.find(build.starting_items)).present?" etc. I have actually given you the correct answer... it's now up to you to write the actual code with correct error checking. Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you are retrieving a list of all items from the database and using them to fill a semantic form. If you take a look at the output of the items in the html it is creating a list of options with the item id as the value of the select.

When the form is saved it saves a string containing the single item ID in the database.

Firstly if you need to accept multiple items you could specify a number of has and belongs to many relationships such as:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :starting_items, :join_table => "items", :foreign_key => "item_id"
```

You then need to make sure that the form actually passed the item id's along to ensure that all of the id's are saved correctly.

Comment: I've changed the `starting_items`, etc. from `string` to `integer` because even though it is SUPPOSED to generate select boxes filled with content - ***emphasis on supposed because the select boxes aren't working. darn you formtastic!*** - the value of this will be an ID just like it does in `active_admin`. I'm going to change the habtm in my model and get back to you.

Comment: Being new to rails and programming in general makes it somewhat hard to communicate for me due to the fact that I just don't know the majority of the terms.

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is to be able to enter the id of an item in my form that later on gets displayed as the item name.

I'm not even sure if the name starting_items is the best for this, or if i should just use `item_id`. Because I'm planning on adding a lot of different inputs where users can enter items that need to be displayed as names.
Do you think the name `starting_items` is good for one of the fields, or should I use `item_id`? 

Isn't there a way I can display the name of an item with ruby by doing something like `Item.name.find(build.starting_items)` or something?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured this on my own after buying a Ruby book.

First, I created a new helper method in application.rb called `starting_item` which goes as  follows:

```
def starting_item(id="6")
    @item = Item.find(id)
    "#{@item.name}"
end
```

Why helper method? This way I can call this method from within my views.
Now, to display the name of the item in my index view, I do just call the method with the argument as follows: `<%= starting_item(build.starting_items) %>`